# primal constrain

Tags: constraints

I'm new to the dual problem.

As you see, here gives one primal problem.

I'm confusing about the constraint $3\leq x_3 \leq 4$, in the textbook I can not find the similar one.

Could anybody teach me how to deal with this kind of constraint? Just a hint is okay. Thank you very much.

$\min \quad x_1+2x_2+3x_3$

$\textrm{s.t.}\quad -x_1+3x_2\quad = 5$

$\quad \quad ~2x_1 - x_2 +3x_3 \geq 6$

$\quad \quad ~ \underline{3\leq x_3\leq4}$

$\quad \quad ~x_1\geq0$

$\quad \quad ~x_2\leq0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate the last contraint $3\le x_3\le 4$ into two contraints such as

$x_3\ge 3$

and $x_3 \le 4$

So you will have five constraints to work with for this minimization problem.

Comment: thank you very much. I will try now.